Images Do Not Work After Transfer
I recently migrated a CiviCRM install from WordPress to Drupal. I am having two problems with images that I am hoping someone can help me with.
First, since migrating over nom images display.  This includes contact images and images in emails.  I have checked that all the paths match another CiviCRM install I volunteer with and that all the paths are correct in the civicrm.settings.php.

When I inspect the missing image with Dev Tools the the file URL does not appear to be correct.  I see: <img src="/civicrm/file?reset=1&amp;filename=Screenshot_2016_06_21_15_36_30_58504175373eec0750cd5f02234c3c4f.png&amp;mime-type=image/png" width="100" height="100/">
The second thing is that I tried to upload an image and I got a page not found when trying to select an image.

The page being loaded is https://crm.chasethemusic.org/libraries/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=crmUiId_1&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en which is not a valid file in my install.
Any help trying to figure these out is greatly appreciated.  I am volunteer with limited time on this project but the org needs to be able to send out mail as soon as possible and we cannot go back to Wordpress (long story).
Thanks,
Steve

If you are on Drupal10 would suggest to use the CKeditor5 extension as there is a bug with KCFinder in d10, if you still want to use KCFinder will need to fix the files manually.

switching the editor fixed this specific issue.  It has not however, fixed the  biggest issue, all my other images throughout CiviCRM are not lading.  I think the issue is what is coming in for [civicrm.files].  I now have files in the editor but nowhere else.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Switching the editor works but the images do not show after being uploaded.  However if I go to version 4 again I see that https://crm.chasethemusic.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/steve_test.png is there and is visable.  Any thoughts on using CKedtior 5 for this.  Thanks!
